# Can I break verbal contract and resign after getting a raise?

Tags: resignation

In January 2015, I gave my resignation as I got a new job offer. But my employer offered me the same salary and asked me to stay. But there was a catch. They told me that I need to stay for an year at least(verbal contract) and I accepted it. Since then, I just hate my job. I spend nearly 5 to 6 hours a day and I hate every second of it. I don't feel like going to work anymore. And today I got a decent raise. Still, I want to quit, really bad. If I resign, does that verbal contract make me look bad for the future employer ?

Comment: A contract is not a contract unless it is in writing. A future employer won't know anything about it, but don't expect to use your boss as a reference.

Comment: Was this agreement a mutual thing, where they also committed to something (other than just to pay you)? Have they made an effort to keep their commitment (e.g., to improve the conditions that caused you to want to leave in the first place)?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Sorry, you are correct. I was hastily trying to make the point that verbal contracts are extremely difficult to enforce, and there's not much to prevent either party from lying about the terms in court.

Comment: You need to speak with an attorney if you are really concerned about the enfocibility of the agreement.  As for "looking bad" - you may not get the best reference, but it won't hurt you.  However, I'd seek some counselling on what you "hate" about the job.  You took the job once, but what's changed?  Lingering resentment?  Different work environment?  What's made you "... hate every second?"

Comment: In January you wanted to leave, but they waited until August to bump your pay?

Comment: It depends if verbal contracts are binding in your domicile - and further what is the penalty (in your contract) for early termination.

Comment: The problem with verbal contracts is it may be unclear what you actually agreed to. For example, in your verbal agreement did you actually say something as concrete as "I agree not resign from this position before 1 January 2016".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I resign, does that verbal contract make me look bad for the future
>   employer ?

At least in the US, unless you or one of your references bring it up, a future employer has no way to know the details of any contracts (verbal or otherwise).

You will certainly be burning some bridges with your current company if you quit now. And others in your current company may think less of you.

It's also possible that you might be asked to pay back some of the increase you received.

But overall, this is very unlikely to make you look bad to future employers.

> Can I break verbal contract and resign after getting a raise?

You can always resign and hope for the best.

As far as can you break a contract - that's a question for an attorney.